# Category dropdown filter in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, quicksort

I want to add a sort option for each category-page like if we open a category page named **category one** which lists all the posts inside **category one** .I need to add a drop down search filter that shows only the posts of that specific category in the dropdown and when its clicked it goes to that specific post page.Please help

Comment: Where did you get stuck when you tried to do this?

Comment: I am getting category drop downs but not post drop downs for a specific category

Comment: Sorry, I mean can you share whatever code you wrote before you gave up and came here?

Comment: actualy i have tried a few plugins